# How to open and update excel workbook from python dash application (as a callback)?

Tags: python, excel, dashboard, plotly-dash, xlwings

I am trying to open, update and run an excel file from a Python Dash application, based on input that a user can select.

The application is trying to access an excel and update specific fields (using xlwings) and then calculate the model and use output from those calculations to draw some graphs.

I have my input fields and then I am trying to do callback and open and excel (I tried to do that both in the callback and at the beginning of the application, both result in the same error).

The code below shows exactly what I am doing. The application runs without errors, but I encounter runtime error that CoInitialize was not initiated.

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)
```

I was trying to start another thread for the Excel, but I couldn't make it work at all.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('my-input', 'value')]
)
def update_output(n_clicks, value):

    fpath = 'file_xlsx.xlsx'
    app = xw.App(visible=True)
    wb = xw.Book(fpath)

    flexible_inputs = wb.sheets['Inputs']

    flexible_inputs.range('F4').value = value

    new_value = value

    return 'Success in changing the value of F4 Flexible Inputs to "{}"'.format(new_value)
```

Any help would be appreciated (also if you have another idea on how to make Dash app update the Excel).

Comment: What version of xlwings are you using?